# Headers of ToC and fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

Please, consider this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}

\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\footnotesize\textsc{#1}}{\footnotesize\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\footnotesize\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\MakeLowercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{La questione degli universali}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\chapter{La questione degli universali}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\chapter{La questione degli universali}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\chapter{La questione degli universali}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\chapter{La questione degli universali}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\chapter{La questione degli universali}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}
\section{Il realismo: l'universale come sostanza}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Gli universali come sostanze in Eriugena}
\subsection{Realismo e teologia nella Scuola di Chartres}

\end{document}
```

In all document, headers are in scshape, but in the ToC in Uppercase.
It seems that fancyhdr has no effect there. I tried some solutions
to change locally the look of ToC header to have the header title "Indice"
in scshape too, but without results. How can I obtain this? Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\tableofcontents` macro issues

```
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
```

which is the cause for your problem. It was a very unfortunate decision made when the class was written.

Also `\listoftables`, `\listoffigures` and `thebibliography` suffer from the same problem. It's not possible to use the `\nouppercase` trick of `fancyhdr`, because you want to lowercase everything.

So a patch seems the safest thing to do (or using `memoir` instead of `report`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\scshape\MakeLowercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize\scshape\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}} 
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
```

Don't use formatting instructions in `\chaptermark` or `\sectionmark`: it's better to state them when defining the headers.

[image]

Comment: Definitive answer from egreg, as usual .-) thanx!