# Bibliography/table of content has chapter in header

Tags: header-footer, pagestyle

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rsc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.25}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=40mm,
    right=20mm,
    top=40mm,
    bottom=50mm
    }
%header settings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
\makeatletter
% copy of the original from report.cls with the \MakeUppercase dropped
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
  \markboth
    {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \@chapapp\ \thechapter. 
      \fi
     #1}
    {}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}

\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape Keiran Corbett}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
  \setlength{\footskip}{50pt}  %page number spacing
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
     \newpage
     text
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \chapter{Example chapter title}
    \end{document}
```

So with this command, it looks how I would like but I have a table of contents and the header for that is Chapter 0. CONTENTS

So I have two questions
1. How do I make CONTENTS not capital
2. How can I get rid of the Chapter (Only for bib and contents section)

bibliography also has the same problem

There is an exmaple of how it should look on page 4 of the example latex file

Comment: I will try come up wtih a MWE. Just having difficulty as it is only on page 2 of the bibliography and page 2 of the contents. It has Chapter 0. CONTENTS as a header (for the second page of the contents) \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

Comment: I cant get the u can use xampl.bib (which is installed on all systems with BibTeX) and \nocite{*} even within the actually document (Very silly error on my part). Thank you for your help

Comment: Okay have recreated it another way anyway using the contents. Even if not very efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a slight change to `\chaptermark` so that `\leftmark` contains the entire header ("Chapter 1. Example chapter title") and not just the chapter title ("Example chapter title"). That makes your `\fancyhead[L]` simpler and less susceptible to incorrect chapter numbers.

For a nice header in the ToC and bibliography I found no better way than patching the commands directly. See for example [Headers of ToC and fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170854/35864).

`memoir` or the KOMA classes would have more convenient interfaces for this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}

\makeatletter
% copy of the original from report.cls with the \MakeUppercase dropped
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth
    {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \@chapapp\ \thechapter. %
      \fi
     #1}
    {}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}

\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape NAME}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Example chapter title}
lorem
\newpage
ipsum
\newpage
dolor
\newpage
sit
\newpage
amet.
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}
\chapter{Example chapter title}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the second page of the ToC. The header reads just "Contents" on the left side]

[image: Screenshot of the second page of the bibliography. The left hand side of the header reads "Bibliography".]

---

The `rsc` package loads `natbib` and thus slightly changes the typesetting of the bibliography heading. In that case you need to patch the command `\bibsection` and not `\thebibliography`.

Add

```
\patchcmd{\bibsection}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\bibsection}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {}
  {}{}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Just one question. It works perfectly on my contents but not on the bibliography - it is still in capitals. I am using the \usepackage{rsc} bibliography style if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Carl I get the same result for the bibliography heading even with `\bibliographystyle{rsc}` in the MWE. If it does not work for you, there must be something *else* that influences the bibliography. Do you load `natbib` or another bibliography *package*? Please add that to your MWE.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rsc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.25}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=40mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=40mm,
 bottom=50mm
 }

Comment: @Carl See the edit, please.

Comment: Done, I dont use natbib as it clashes with rsc

Comment: @Carl Mhhh, `rsc` loads `natbib`, the two definitely don't clash in that regard. Things might clash if you load `rsc` *and* manually load `natbib` as well. Does the solution work for you?

Comment: Well I have edited the orignal post to include all MWE as I cant figure out which one is causing the error

Comment: @Carl In the edited post you patch `\thebibliography`, but in my edit I suggest to patch `\bibsection` instead. (Each command needs to be patched twice.) Did you try that?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for all this - (Sorry it took so long - I will try make it clearer if there is a next time)